# How can I load an URL with an Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, url

I'm trying to find how I can load a webpage when the user click on my image (in a UIImageView).
example:
If the user click on the logo google,the application will go on www.google.fr.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to react to a "tap" gesture on the ImageView.

On iOS 3.2 and later, this is made very easy by UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[recognizer release];
```

.. then, in the tap handler, you can open your url:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]];
```

References:

[UITapGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UIApplication Class Reference / openURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW14)